# error al iniciar la aplicación ios por error de SIGABRT. __abort_with_payload + 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have an app in production at the moment, but on some iphone 11 devices with ios 13.6.1 the app srtart the splash and closes automatically.

we have tested on test devices and emulators and the app works fine, in app center I get the following log

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x18726f858
Crashed Thread:  6

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018726f858 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000187273f0c abort_with_payload + 12
2   TCC                                  0x000000018d80dbac __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 192
3   TCC                                  0x000000018d80dae8 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.130 + 572
4   TCC                                  0x000000018d811d38 __tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 260
5   libxpc.dylib                         0x000000018708e4c4 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 88
6   libxpc.dylib                         0x00000001870825b4 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 84
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018712b634 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000187143988 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 340
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018713b3c8 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1192
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000187191750 _pthread_wqthread + 328
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001871979c8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018724e784 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   IOKit                                0x000000018847be74 io_connect_method + 436
2   IOKit                                0x00000001884056cc IOConnectCallMethod + 232
3   IOSurface                            0x00000001910bfefc IOSurfaceClientCreate + 172
4   IOSurface                            0x00000001910be958 -[IOSurface initWithProperties:] + 76
5   CoreUI                               0x00000001947f06e8 __csiCompressImageProviderCopyIOSurfaceWithOptions + 1396
6   QuartzCore                           0x000000018dfa6c5c CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double) + 1924
7   QuartzCore                           0x000000018dfa7cd0 CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 20
8   QuartzCore                           0x000000018e0e7624 CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 496
9   QuartzCore                           0x000000018e02be1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 312
10  QuartzCore                           0x000000018e0568c4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 680
11  QuartzCore                           0x000000018e0574b4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
12  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018740411c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001873fee4c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
14  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001873ff2dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1000
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001873febc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
16  GraphicsServices                     0x00000001917e05cc GSEventRunModal + 160
17  UIKitCore                            0x000000018b5b1744 UIApplicationMain + 1932
18  xxxx               0x00000001031c41e8 0x102804000 + -2874807840984530456
19  xxxx               0x000000010320a814 0x102804000 + 10512404
20  xxxx               0x000000010407e34c 0x102804000 + 25666380
21  xxxx               0x0000000104139828 0x102804000 + 26433576
22  xxxx               0x000000010413fa80 0x102804000 + 26458752
23  xxxx               0x000000010405c904 0x102804000 + 25528580
24  xxxx               0x0000000104210ad8 0x102804000 + 27314904
25  xxxx               0x0000000102d238b8 0x102804000 + 5372088
26  libdyld.dylib                        0x000000018727b384 start + 0
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

and in the testflight log it shows this

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Signal: Abort trap: 6
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x6
Terminating Process: xxxxx  [10883]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b598063c __mmap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b5964c88 mmap + 104 (mmap.c:61)
2   CoreUI                          0x00000001c2ef8578 -[_CSIRenditionBlockData _allocateImageBytes] + 140 (CUIThemeRendition.m:1059)
3   CoreUI                          0x00000001c2ef7718 -[_CSIRenditionBlockData initWithPixelWidth:pixelHeight:sourceRowbytes:pixelFormat:] + 128 (CUIThemeRendition.m:568)
4   CoreUI                          0x00000001c2efffac __csiCompressImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions + 992 (CUIThemeRendition.m:1375)
5   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001bca1e390 subImageProviderCopyImageBlockSet + 344 (CGImageProvider.c:400)
6   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc6b75a8 CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double) + 4308 (render-image-cache.cpp:1235)
7   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc6b7cd0 CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 24 (render-image-cache.cpp:1721)
8   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc7f7624 CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*) + 500 (CALayer.mm:2522)
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc73be1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 316 (CAContextInternal.mm:1998)
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc7668c4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc7674b4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 96 (CATransactionInternal.mm:890)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5b1411c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5b0ee4c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420 (CFRunLoop.c:1868)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5b0f2dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1004 (CFRunLoop.c:2910)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b5b0ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bfef05cc GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2246)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b9cc1744 UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4823)
18  xxxx            0x0000000105570d18 0x104b9c000 + 10308888
19  xxxx            0x00000001055b846c 0x104b9c000 + 10601580
20  xxxx            0x00000001055b83d0 0x104b9c000 + 10601424
21  xxxx            0x00000001050d9d28 0x104b9c000 + 5496104
22  xxxx            0x000000010523b7a0 0x104b9c000 + 6944672
23  xxxx            0x0000000106462f34 0x104b9c000 + 25980724
24  xxxx            0x000000010651e5e8 0x104b9c000 + 26748392
25  xxxx            0x0000000106524840 0x104b9c000 + 26773568
26  xxxx            0x00000001064414ec 0x104b9c000 + 25842924
27  xxxx            0x00000001065f58a8 0x104b9c000 + 27629736
28  xxxx            0x00000001050bb8b8 0x104b9c000 + 5372088
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b598b384 start + 4
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Have a check with [Accessing Private User Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows#accessing-private-user-data) in iOS device.Whether there are permissions not be added in `info.plist` file.

Comment: I suggest you to check few things.
1. __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__  "Please check, whether you have given all the required permissions in info.plist file" like for eg: "App Transport Security Settings"
2. Are you calling any api, on splash screen ?
3. Have you tested in iphone 11 devices with ios 13.6.1 or simulator ?
4. After Splash screen, where it is redirecting either login or home screen. Please try to review your code once

Comment: Hi. 1-all the permissions that are needed were requested, and the app works correctly with all the functionalities in different devices 2- if two apis are being called. 3-yes, we already tested on iphone 11 with ios 13.6.1 and simulators and it works correctly.
4-after the splash screen directs you to the login screen.

Comment: @alexiscorrea Have a check with the network of some iphones that not work. You also can close the network of iphone to test whehter it will occur the same phenomenon.

Comment: The information you provided is not enough, is there any more information you can provide? 1) What libraries are you using in the app? 2) Is it happening for devices <iOS 13 in Production? 3) Do you need to add bluetooth/picture/camera permissions by any chance ? 4) If you compare the build settings between Debug and Release of you iOS project options, what differences do you see? 5) Could you share some of the initialization code in your Main?

Comment: @Saamer 1 1. I am using firebase.
2. only happens on some devices above ios 13
3. I am adding location, camera and face ID permissions
4.I see no difference
5. I can't share code